# libopencv_highgui.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros

When I try to catkin build my workspace, I get this error:

```
CMakeFiles/openpose_ros_node_firephinx.dir/src/openpose_ros_node_firephinx.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv7waitKeyEi'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line.
```

I have tried to add the OpenCV library manually to the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but the problem is persisting.

This is how I am including OpenCV:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/share/OpenCV NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: It seems to be a linkage error, thus it may depend on the lib you link to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I added `opencv_highgui` to the `target_link_libraries()` in the CMake file to solve the problem.